# Release TextFormField focus on hardware back button press

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a `TextFormField` in a flutter app and its Focus is important to the functionality of my screen. When the field has focus, I hide some widgets on the page so it looks good when the keyboard is open.

When I press the back button to exit the field, the keyboard is minimized, but the field still maintains focus. So the widgets I hid on the screen are still hidden. As soon as I tap out of focus, the widgets come back, but I know users will get confused at why the back button did not make the widget re-appear. I know I can release the focus by requesting a new focus:

```dart
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
```

But, I don't know where I can invoke this release focus logic. I thought I might be able to create an `EventChannel` to subscribe to the native activity `onBackButtonPressed()` and send back button events down the channel, but it looks like an [open issue to be able to override this function in a Flutter app](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23211).

I know there is a `WillPopScope` widget that allows you to capture the back button event if it will exit the current `ModalRoute`, but I'm not sure I can use this to solve my problem because the widget of interest is a `TextFormField` not a `ModalRoute`.

Is there a way I can subscribe to the keyboard closing instead?

Comment: Why do you hide widgets when displaying the keyboard and then show back after disposing it, in first place? Looks like you are trying to prevent overflow in a non-elegant way. If so, you don’t need all of that work, just wrap your view in `SingleChildScrollView` and you should be good to go, the keyboard will appear and the content be scrollable if there isn’t enough space.

Comment: My screen has two user flow options: scan a QR code or enter in a pin code. When the user focuses in on the pin code input, that is the only thing on my page that is relevant to them. They don't need to scroll to see other content because only the focused text field needs to be filled out for them to move on.

Answer (score 0):

When I got to the end of typing out my problem, I thought of the idea to subscribe to the keyboard closing event... sure enough there is a package for that! https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_visibility

So, I can solve my problem by using the `keyboard_visibility` package

```dart
import 'package:keyboard_visibility/keyboard_visibility.dart';
// ...
final FocusNode roomIdInputFocusNode = FocusNode();
final roomIdHasFocus = BehaviorSubject<bool>();
// ...
roomIdHasFocus.sink.add(false);
roomIdInputFocusNode.addListener(() {
    roomIdHasFocus.sink.add(roomIdInputFocusNode.hasFocus);
});
KeyboardVisibilityNotification().addNewListener(
    onChange: (bool visible) {
        if (!visible) {
            roomIdHasFocus.sink.add(false);
        } else if (visible && roomIdInputFocusNode.hasFocus) {
            roomIdHasFocus.sink.add(true);
        }
    },
);
```

Unfortunately, this still keeps the focus on the TextFormField, but it is good enough for me because I'm able to unhide the widgets I hid away when the keyboard opened.